# Change color of specific ytick matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `dict` with 200 keys and values that generates this graph.[image]

Also i compute the average of these values and plot that too. I would like the avg value to be the same color as the line. The code that i use is this :

```
with open('path_to_json/values.json', 'r') as outfile:
    a = json.load(outfile)

sum = 0
for k, v in a.items():
    sum += v

avg = sum / len(a.values())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
p=ax.plot(list(a.keys()),list(a.values()))
p=ax.plot([0, len(a.values())], [avg, avg], "--")
yt = ax.get_yticks()
yt = np.append(yt, avg)
xticks = np.arange(0, len(a.values()), 10)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_yticks(yt)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I agree with @finefoot. The answer for setting `xticks` is here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html. I would suggest removing that part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the overview for the [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels) class, especially the "Ticks and tick labels" section: There's `get_yticklabels` and `get_yticklines` which return the objects which both have a `set_color` method.

Minimal example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yticks(np.append(ax.get_yticks(), 0.55))
ax.get_yticklabels()[-1].set_color("red")
ax.get_yticklines()[-2].set_color("red")
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 1]